# What happens to a file created if user does not take photo?

Tags: android, file, camera

If I create an implicit intent for a user to take a photo, and he does not (quits, kills the app, cancels some how), what happens to the file I have created below ?

I have the following:

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I am guessing I need to override onActivityResult to check this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //
        ...
    }else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode != RESULT_OK){
  //Cleanup here ?
}
```

}

Is that right ? Should I be deleting the file in onActivityResult, if the result is not ok ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a temp file to begin with. The only thing you need to create and to provide is a file name. A file path.  In your case a File instance.

Comment: Can you explain why ? The code I pasted is from the official example on: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Yes i know its an official example. And very bad code. You already discovered why.

Comment: but you can just delete the file right ? Do you have a code sample of what I should actually do ?

Comment: Yes you can delete that file. But it is the wrong aproach. Do not create that file to begin with. It is not needed. We are here to help you writing good code. Not to help you writing wrong code.